# Why does $e^{t+4}(t-1)=0$ only yield one solution?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms, roots, eulers-number-e

I understand that $e^{t+4}(t-1)=0$ only yields one solution because $e^x >0$ what I am wondering is why you can't $\ln$ to cancel out the $e$ to give $(t+4)(t-1)=0$

This is clearly invalid from looking at online resources and there's also no need to do it but Maths doesn't lie after all and I'm wondering why this wouldn't be possible. The only thing I can possibly think of is that you have to $\ln 0$ on the right hand side despite it being $0$

Comment: To cancel our an exponent, you need to take a log. That would require that you put the $t-1$ term into the exponent, too. Remember that $\ln(ab) = \ln(a) + \ln(b) $. You could in theory work with $\ln(0)$ if you want to pretend that it is the same as $-\infty $. This is slightly dangerous if you're not exceedingly careful however and is generally not a good idea. (I would certainly dock points for it.)

Comment: Working just on the left hand side: if you take $\ln$ you would get $t+4+\ln(t-1).$ As far as the right hand side, as others have noted, $\ln(0)$ is not defined.

Comment: It's very helpful to know that $e^{\text{anything}}$ is never zero. For example because $e^z e^{-z} = 1$. It's not going to be zero if you can multiply it by something and get $1$. So you are solving $[\text{nonzero}] \times (t-1) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I suspected that you would have to $\ln$ the $0$ which would be undefined, I'm just so used to dealing with numbers

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $e^{t+4}(t-1) = 0$ is factored. That is you have set up a product of two terms that's equal to zero. That would imply that: $t-1 = 0$ or $e^{t+4} = 0$. For the equation, $e^{t+4} = 0$, to isolate for the exponent $t+4$, you would have to take $ln$ of both sides. But the value of $ln(0)$ is undefined. The reason it's undefined is that the domain of $ln(x)$ is $\{x \in \mathbb{R} | x > 0\}$. This is precisely a consequence of the fact that $e^x > 0$, as you point out in your question. Since $lnx$ is the inverse operation to $e^x$ the Range of $e^x$ is also the Domain of $lnx$

That all said, to answer your question about why you can't take the $ln$ of your original equation, not only would you be calculating $ln(0)$, but your algebra is off. You can't just take the $ln$ of one term in a product. In abstract, you could do: $ln(e^{t+4}(t-1)) = ln(e^{t+4}) + ln(t-1)) = t+4 + ln(t-1)$, but I'm not sure that's a very helpful algebraic manipulation. But even then, in the context of this question, if you did $ln(e^{t+4}(t-1))$, you would also have to take the $ln$ of the other side, $0$, and as mentioned, $ln(0)$ is undefined.

Comment: MathJax tip: use the Latex command `\ln` to produce better looking natural logarithms. For example, `$ln(t - 1)$` produces $ln(t - 1)$, while `$\ln(t - 1)$` produces $\ln(t - 1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @TheoBendit !

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I suspected you would have to $\ln$ the RHS $0$ despite it being $0$, I'm just so used to dealing with numbers that I wasn't completely sure. As for the taking $ln$ of one term in a product that is again a symptom of being used to numbers and forgetting the $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$ rule. None of this is necessary for the question but I'm glad I asked as it's always good to iron out fundamentals, I have Calculus soon!

Comment: Happy to help! Yes, the main issue here is that ln(0) is undefined but I wanted to show that if you were able to simplify the left side you'd have to use the product rule for logs. In any event, certainly for calculus and higher maths, the fundamentals are always very important to be aware of. I'd recommend brushing up on those and with respect to logs remember there's also the quotient, exponential and change of base rule which are extremely helpful to know

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to use $\ln$ on both sides you get

$\ln [e^{t+4}(t-1)] = \ln 0$

$\ln (e^{t+4}) + \ln (t-1) = \ln 0$

$t+4 + \ln(t-1) = \ln 0$.

And from here we *could* not the RHS is undefined $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x=-\infty$.  So we must have the LEFT also undefined.  So $t-1 \le 0$.  But if $t-1 < 0$ then we don't have any value for $\lim_{x\to t-1} \ln x$ not even $-\infty$. As $x$ can't be *near* $t-1$ if $t-1 < 0$ then no limit makes any sense.

So we must have $t-1 = 0$ and $t =1$.

So... you can *almost* do that.

.......

What you seem to want to do is selectively apply $\ln e^{t+4}$ but *NOT* apply it to $(t-1)$ and .... you just can't do that.

You certainly can *NOT* say $[e^{t+4} ](t-1) = 0$ so $[\ln e^{t+4}](t-1) = 0$.  That's just nutty.  $A\ne \ln A$ so it make no sense to say $AB = (\ln A)B$ but that's exactly what you are trying to say.

Comment: Yes, I realise now that I was treating what I was attempting to do as if I were simply dealing with integers e.g. $(t+4)(t-1)=0$ is the same as $2(t+4)(t-1)=0$ but as $\ln$ is a logarithmic function you must apply the log product rule otherwise the information is lost. It's been a while since I did logs so not everything was fresh in my mind, currently preparing for Calculus. Thanks for the help!

Comment: But $(t+4)(t-1)=0 \implies 2(t+4)(t-1) = 2\times 0$ when you "multiply both sides" you are mutlitplying the entire term by $2$; not just the $(t+4)$ term. This would be like trying to add to both sides and getting $(t+4 +2)(t-1)= 0+2$ so $(t+6)(t-1) = 2$.

Comment: Yes, my logic was $2(ab)$ is the same as $2ab$ but applying multiplication rules to logs was the error. As for zero, I'm so used to treating anything times zero as zero when it's a lot more than that and undefined $\neq 0$